# Rails wrong date arithmetic result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting a weird result:

```
2.3.1 :001 > Time.now
 => 2017-05-01 16:59:00 -0300 
2.3.1 :002 > Time.now - 1.month - 3.days
 => 2017-03-29 16:59:10 -0300 
2.3.1 :003 > Time.now - 1.month - 3.days + 1.month + 3.days
 => 2017-05-02 16:59:19 -0300
```

The final result should be 2017-05-01 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. `ActiveSupport::Duration` does some work behind the scenes to make working with dates more intuitive. Take this example:

```
Time.now + 1.month
```

No matter what month `Time.now` is, the result is always 1 month ahead regardless of the number of the days in the month. Feb 1 goes to Mar 1. Mar 1 goes to Apr 1.

When you use the calls like you have, though, you do this:

```
time = Time.now
time - 1.month #=> April 1
time - 3.days #=> March 29
time + 1.month #=> April 29
time + 3.days #=> May 2 (three days after Apr 29)
```

If you wanted to change this behavior, you could convert these ActiveSupport::Duration instances into absolute seconds, then it works either way:

```
temporal_offset = 1.month + 3.days
time = Time.now
time - temporal_offset.to_i + temporal_offset.to_i
#=> (same time as Time.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `-/+ 1.month` advances or backtracks exactly one month, which can be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days. This strange, but ultimataly correct behavior, is because March has 31 days but April 30.

So with

```
2017-05-01 - 1.month = 30 days
2017-04-01 - 1.month = 31 days
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's calculating it sequentially:

```
2.3.3 :001 > Time.now
 => 2017-05-01 16:05:12 -0400
2.3.3 :002 > Time.now - 1.month
 => 2017-04-01 16:05:14 -0400
2.3.3 :003 > Time.now - 1.month - 3.days
 => 2017-03-29 16:05:17 -0400
2.3.3 :004 > Time.now - 1.month - 3.days + 1.month
 => 2017-04-29 16:05:19 -0400
2.3.3 :005 > Time.now - 1.month - 3.days + 1.month + 3.days
 => 2017-05-02 16:05:22 -0400
```